# show element and hide the other elements within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display list of names and when click on the name it will show the country for that name , and when click on other name it will hide the previous one and show the clicked one only,
i used ng-show with variable declared in the controller but it just keep showing each items i click on it without hiding the others, this is my code:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
  <a href="#" ng-click="showDesc = true">{{x.Name}}</a>
  <div ng-show="showDesc">{{x.Country}}</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.showDesc = false;
      $scope.records = [
        {
          "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
          "Country" : "Germany"
        },
        {
          "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
          "Country" : "Sweden"
        },
        {
          "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
          "Country" : "Mexico"
        },
        {
          "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
          "Country" : "Austria"
        }
      ]
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your showDesc is just a general property, not bound to each element in your list. So when you set showDesc, it will set $scope.showDesc (which applies for every record in your repeater)

Comment: @thsorens that's incorrect. Read my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-repeat has its own scope. So `showDesc = true` initializes a `showDesc` field in the ng-repeat scope. Each item has its own showDesc.

You want a global flag, common to all the items. And that can't just be a flag: you need to know **which** item must be expanded.

So just change the code to

```
$scope.expandedRecord = null;
$scope.expand = function(record) {
  $scope.expandedRecord = record;
}
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
  <a href="#" ng-click="expand(x)">{{x.Name}}</a>
  <div ng-show="expandedRecord === x">{{x.Country}}</div>
</div>
```